# IP allocation status

Tags: ubuntu, ip, lan

I am on a Lan network so i was wondering if their is any way to know how many IP's have been allocated and how many IP's are free on the network via Terminal commands ?
I am running Ubuntu OS.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to help you out: http://nmap.org/

Lets say you wish to search your network, which is 192.168.0.0/16

```
nmap 192.168.0-255.1-254
```

example output:

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-06-09 12:36 CEST
Nmap scan report for DD-WRT (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.042s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
53/tcp open  domain
80/tcp open  http
```

I never personally used it but it supposedly can help you map your network and you'll just need to know your network information to utilize it.

If you have a router and access to the router then you can access admin panel and check the DHCP clients for record information as well.

Comment: I was wondering if i could do that with terminal commands ?

Comment: Nmap can be run from the terminal. http://nmap.org/book/man-target-specification.html

Comment: `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/16` is better.  `-sP` only performs a ping and scans a couple of ports.  By default, you're scanning many more per host, which takes longer.